# XCUI tests failing on iOS 10 but not iOS 9 due to ""Error -25204 getting snapshot for element"

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode-ui-testing

I have created a test suite for XCUItesting for my app...However since the upgrade (unsure if relevant) to xcode 8 and the use of ios10 simulator my test cases will only run in the ios9 and not in the 10. When I run the tests in the ios 10 simulator I get the error `Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot Error Domain=XCTestManagerErrorDomain Code=9 "Error -25204 getting snapshot for element <AXUIElement 0x7fe2a6614ad0> {pid=7751}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error -25204 getting snapshot for element <AXUIElement 0x7fe2a6614ad0> {pid=7751}}`

Is anyone experincing this also?
Or
Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: I have run into the same issue. Any update on this one?

Answer (score 2):

## Root cause

I have run into the same issue. The test was failing with the same error but the root cause was that the app was crashing. I set up an exception breakpoint and printed the backtrace out to see where.

In the end, it was a crash caused by implicitly unwrapped optional in one of the `uitableviewdelegate`'s method signatures:

`public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool`

This method was called by the system during the UI tests with `indexPath` parameter being `nil`, causing the app to hang.

The backtrace showed this:

```
(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #1: tid = 0x128eaa, 0x000000010c776c3a libswiftFoundation.dylib`static Foundation.IndexPath._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSIndexPath>) -> Foundation.IndexPath + 42, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010c776c3a libswiftFoundation.dylib`static Foundation.IndexPath._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSIndexPath>) -> Foundation.IndexPath + 42
    frame #1: 0x0000000108443241 Static`@objc DataSource.tableView(UITableView, canPerformAction : Selector, forRowAt : IndexPath, withSender : Any?) -> Bool + 97 at DataSource.swift:0
    frame #2: 0x00000001095aea31 UIKit`-[UITableView _canPerformAction:forCell:sender:] + 169
    frame #3: 0x00000001098017c6 UIKit`-[UITableViewCell canPerformAction:withSender:] + 86
    frame #4: 0x00000001210a5fc9 UIKit`-[UIResponder(UITextAccessibilityUtilities) _accessibilityHasTextOperations] + 100
    frame #5: 0x000000012107bb7c UIKit`-[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement _accessibilityHasTextOperations] + 48
    frame #6: 0x00000001211f09ec UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:] + 5945
    frame #7: 0x000000012120bc04 UIAccessibility`_accessibilityAttributesForObject + 767
    frame #8: 0x000000012120b5e8 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingSnapshotDescendantsWithAttributes:maxDepth:maxChildren:maxArrayCount:] + 1736
    frame #9: 0x000000012120cf96 UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingSnapshotWithOptions:] + 557
    frame #10: 0x00000001211eec0a UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:forParameter:] + 7903
    frame #11: 0x00000001211d8856 UIAccessibility`_copyParameterizedAttributeValueCallback + 211
    frame #12: 0x0000000120869532 AXRuntime`_AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 216
    frame #13: 0x0000000120863f1c AXRuntime`_XCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 440
    frame #14: 0x0000000120872de5 AXRuntime`mshMIGPerform + 266
    frame #15: 0x00000001064e93d9 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    frame #16: 0x00000001064e9351 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 465
    frame #17: 0x00000001064e1435 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    frame #18: 0x00000001064e0884 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    frame #19: 0x000000010e5bda6f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #20: 0x000000010943dc68 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
    frame #21: 0x000000010462c95f GoOut`main + 111 at AppDelegate.swift:47
    frame #22: 0x000000010cb7e68d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #23: 0x000000010cb7e68d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

### Solution

After knowing which method was causing it, the fix is quite simple -- just replace the `indexPath` type with optional `IndexPath?` (add the question mark):

`public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool`

Then the method gets called properly with `nil` and does not cause crashes.

For more info see: https://openradar.appspot.com/31375101 and feel free to dupe the radar.

Comment: Great stuff man, sorry for the delayed reply! Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using swift 2 or swift 3.  I seem to run into that error often when using the `.hittable` (swift 2) or .`isHittable`(swift 3) check.  See if removing the hittable check helps.  There are other options than the built in hittable check.